# Without public fields, how to make a reference to UI Objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a UI Panel with a Text element as a child; it has the PlayerHUB script attached to it which will handle the update. I have a `GameObject` called Player with a Script called "BaseStats" attached to it and it has a String Variable called Name set to "Red" and finally I have a "BattleManager" Script attached to a empty game object called Battle Manager.

All I want to do is, through code (no public fields), have the "BattleManager" script change the text which is a child to the U.I panel to the name of the Player character "Red", but It is not working at I cant find out why.

Problem is pointing me here:

```
void Start()
{

    playerHUB.SetUP(baseStats);
}
```

Here is my BaseStats script attached to the Player:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class BaseStats : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string Name = "Red";
}
```

Here is the PlayerHUB script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerHUB : MonoBehaviour
{
    Text nameText;

    public void SetUP(BaseStats baseStats)
    {
        nameText = GameObject.Find("PlayerHUB").GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
        nameText.text = baseStats.Name;
    }
}
```

And Finally BattleManger Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


    public class BattleManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        PlayerHUB playerHUB;
        BaseStats baseStats;


        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            playerHUB = GetComponent<PlayerHUB>();
            baseStats = GetComponent<BaseStats>();
            playerHUB.SetUP();
        }    
    }
```

Comment: make that field a property `public string Name {get;set;} = "Red"`. If you BaseStats can not be used by itself - make it abstract and make the property abstract as well. Also consider using `nameof(PlayerHUB)` instead of a string const in code, aka "magic value"

Comment: Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and use data binding.

Comment: Are you getting any sort of errors on the console?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting  Nullreference: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  Its looking for something but I don't know what it wants...

Answer (score 0):

GetComponent will only find scripts attached to the same game object, and returns null if there is not one attached, which is why you are getting a NullReference error. Try `FindObjectOfType<PlayerHub>()` instead. This will work if you only have one instance of the script in your scene. In cases where you have multiple instances of a script and need references to them, `FindObjectsOfType<ScritpName>()` will return a list of all scripts of that type in your scene.